# Importar el módulo python-dateutil en web2py

Tags: python, web2py

Estoy usando la versión de `python 2.7.11` y he descargado el módulo `dateutil 1.5` del cual he copiado el contenido de este dentro de la carpeta `modules`en `web2py`, la importación de este modulo lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
from modules.dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

Ya que es la que necesito en este momento, pero al ejecutar me aparece el siguiente error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber qué estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando copias una librería a la carpeta `modules`, lo que hace web2py es buscarlo ahi antes de buscarlo en el `sys.path`.

Por lo tanto, tu importación no debería incluir la carpeta `modules` en sí, debería ser simplemente:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

Comment: Funciono! , muchas gracias